# If dim$(V)=n<\infty$, then $V^{\infty}_{p} = V_{p^n}$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

Fixed $V$ vector space and  $T\in$ End$(V,V)$ and given $p\in P(\mathbb{F})$ polynomial over the field $\mathbb{F}$, we denote:

$V_p = \{v \in V: p(T)(v) = 0\}$

and

$V^{\infty}_{p} = \bigcup_{k> 0 } V_{p^k}$.

The problem is:

> If dim$(V)=n<\infty$, then  $V^{\infty}_{p} = V_{p^n}$

I'm having trouble in order to formalize and clearly justify the proof. Here is my attempt:

First we may note that given any polynomials $p,f$, it is true that $V_p\subseteq V_{pf}$, since $f(T)(p(T)(v)) = f(T)(0) = 0 $ for all $v\in V_p$.

In fact it follows that $V_{p^k}\subseteq V_{p^{k+1}}$ for all $k$ natural.

We also note that if $V_p \subseteq V_f$ and $g\neq 0$, then $V_{pg} \subseteq V_{fg}$, since if $v\in V_{pg}$ and $v\not\in V_{fg}$, we have $g(T)(p(T)(v)) = 0$ and $g(T)(f(T)(v)) \neq 0$, which shows that $v\in V_p$ and $v\not\in V_f$. With those results, we have the following proposition:

> If  $V_{p^k} = V_{p^{k+1}}$ for some $k\in \mathbb{N}$, then $V_{p^m} = V_{p^k}$ for all $m\geq k $.

which can be shown by induction ( i have typped the proof here but somehow i lost it).

Now we can prove our main goal. If we suppose that they are different, we are supposing that $V_{p^m}\not\subseteq V_{p^n}$ for some $m\geq n$. We can now use the contrapositive of our proposition, which gives us the result that $V_{p^{k+1}}\not\subseteq V_{p^k}$ for all $k$ natural.

How can i use this to clearly (it seems intuitive of course) contradict the finite dimension of the space?

Comment: Do you mean $p\in\Bbb F[x]$?

Comment: Yes. It is a polynomial

Comment: What is $\text{End}(V,V)$?

Comment: Endomorphism. All linear transformation from V to V.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have proven that if $V_{p^k} = V_{p^{k+1}}$ then $V_{p^m} = V_{p^k}$ for $m\geq k$ you're almost there. You have to notice that $V_{p^k}$ is a vector space. It is a subspace of $V$ so it can maximal be of dimension $n$. So it has to stop "growing" at some point. And it will do so latest for $n$....